# Firebase security rules with non-homogeneous structure

Tags: firebase-security, rules

I have a firebase with the following structure:

```
MyProject/
  Global/
  user1_email/
  user2_email/
  ...
```

The Global node is accessible to all, user1_email, user2_email etc are accessible to the specific login users. How to I write the security rules?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Based on the documentation here, you should be able to make a good start on this use-case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started